# php cli-server is not loading woff fonts

Tags: php, server

I am creating a server based on cli-server. so far I did this;

```php
tlog("Starting server at $address in $port port." . PHP_EOL); // Simple error_log() function
exec("php -S " . $address . ":" . $port . " -t assets/ index.php");
```

on index.php I have a 404 catcher route like;

```php
$router->add("/.*", function () {
    // Handling Asset Files
    if (file_exists(ROOT . ltrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"][0]))) {
        if (strtolower(pathinfo(ROOT . ltrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"][0]), PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) === "woff")
            header('Content-Type: font/woff');
        header('Content-Type: ' . get_mime_type(ROOT . ltrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"][0])));
        print readfile(ROOT . ltrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"][0]));
        exit();
    }
    global $page;
    $page->title = "404 Not Found | " . SITE_NAME;
    handle_404();
});
```

When I try to include font awesome with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome-4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">` it generates error.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i357F.png)

get_mime_type function;

```
function get_mime_type($file)
    {
        $mime_type = array(
            '.woff' => 'font/woff',
            '.woff2' => 'font/woff2',
            '.eot' => 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject',
            '.otf' => 'font/otf',
            '.ttf' => 'font/ttf',
        );

        $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        if (isset($mime_type[$extension])) {
            return $mime_type[$extension];
        } else if (isset($mime_type["." . $extension])) {
            return $mime_type["." . $extension];
        } else if ($extension === "2-dev") {
            return null;
        } else {
            return clog("mime_err_unknwn: Unknown file type Extension: " . $extension);
        }
    }
```

other mime types are working successfully. Such as images, css, js etc.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't tell us much, is that just the 404? Is it _your_ 404 or PHP's? Are you able to log all of the requests verbatim so that you can visually confirm what is being sent matches?

Comment: Yes, all the requests are sent successfully. I noticed that server is returning text/html content type. But I have set content type font/woff already. it is not effecting it.

Comment: by 404 I meant all requests

Comment: Also, I hope this is for internal use only, right? The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) makes it pretty clear that this should never be used in a production/public environment.

Comment: yes it is. it is just for development and testing purposes.

Comment: the server is a part of framework project. and it is only for development purposes.

Comment: Irrelevant side note: I can't help notice that you generally use double-quoted strings, the string syntax that implements variable parsing, yet always close quotes before feeding variables, as in `"." . $extension`.

Comment: I don't get it. some of extensions come with .. idont know why. that's why I use "."

Comment: When you inspect the 404 in your browser, is there a body? At this point, ignore the CSS completely and only try the absolute URL to the WOFF file. I'm tryin got see if either of you `if` statements are hitting, or if your fallback `handle_404` is hitting

Comment: There is no body in woff file.

Comment: Sorry I just checked it again. The woff file has 404 handler function.

Comment: With version query like fontawesome.woff?v=4.6.1 it displays 404. without the query it downloads woff file.

Comment: It sounds like you have your answer then? You just need to add logic to handle/exclude the querystring.

Comment: Yeah I am trying it now :D

Comment: If I were you, I'd add some logging to this specific router. Every `if` statement should be prefixed with a log entry of `Looking for file XYZ`, then the `if`, and then the result, both for success and failure. Be very literal in this logging, too. Don't duplicate code either like you are doing. Any concatenation/path logic should be moved to a variable so that a tiny typo doesn't bite you. Also, I didn't look too hard, but I think you could run into path traversal issues for code accidentally breaking out of root.

Comment: That's a good point and I have solution which is working. To avoid typo requests my I put ```$router->add("/.*", function () {``` in bottom of my code.

Comment: I'd also point out that PHP has a [built-in function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for parsing the URL into the various parts which would avoid the need for RegEx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone has the same problem here's the solution;

```php
// Handling Asset Files
    // Some of the asset files can include version strings such as ?v=1.0.0 we need to avoid those to access extension correctly.
    // So preg_replace will help alot. Lets use it then.
    $requested_file = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', ROOT . ltrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"][0]));
    // now we need to check if the file exists in our directory?
    if (file_exists($requested_file)) {
        // if it does we send content type mime to server
        header('Content-Type: ' . get_mime_type($requested_file));
        // And the body of the file that requested.
        print readfile($requested_file);
        // Adding exit function to avoid 404 error handler.
        exit();
    }
```

I explained line by line. if you don't get it just comment and I will try to answer.